# Automatic updates on NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, gitlab, pm2

I recently developed my own CMS using `NodeJS` and `Sequelize/MySQL`. I'd like to create an action to update automaticaly the project using `Gitlab` or something like this... To start the CMS I use `PM2`.

Any idea?

What the action should do :

1. Get latest files on `Gitlab` using a specific `.gitignore`
2. Restart the app using `PM2`

Anthony,

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jenkins and git hook.
It can detects and pulls your app changes, and able to call pm2 reload command.

Comment: Ah... Perhaps I didn't understand the question.
I guessed "automatic update the node.js app".